# Why does this statement work when it is part of a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I see that this SQL statement works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Company 
LEFT JOIN (
   Departments 
   INNER JOIN Employees 
   ON Departments.dep_id = Employees.Dep_ID
   ) ON Company.compId = Departments.Comp_ID;
```

But this statement:

```
 Departments INNER JOIN Employees ON Departments.dep_id = Employees.Dep_ID
```

can not be parsed.

Is this meant to be a short version only for subqueries?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question without more context.  Please edit your question to show the complete query that does not work.  By the way, the query that works does not have a subquery, it just has some superfluous parentheses.

Comment: @DanBracuk:The query that does not work is the second statement.It is what is inside the parenthesis after the `LEFT JOIN` of the first query

Comment: @Cratylus The statement inside parenthesis is not subquery and can't be used as query. It is joined tables.

Comment: The expression inside the brackets is ***not*** a subquery.

Comment: @Perception:Why not?It is creating a table on the fly to be used as the right part of the left join

Comment: I'm confused; you start by saying the SQL statement works but then say something "cannot be parsed".  Does the query work as written and you want to understand how it works **OR** is there an error?  And to be clear, the part driving your `LEFT JOIN` is called a derived table, not a sub-query.

Comment: @Cratylus, it might be your intent to create a table on the fly, but that's not what you did.  All you did was to put part of your from clause inside brackets.

Comment: I Agree with @DanBracuk . You are just using parenthesis to envelope or group some clauses, this doesn't mean you are creating a subquery just because of that. eg.: `select (1 + 2) * 3;` Anyway, try using the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) keyword to make MySQL show you what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Departments INNER JOIN Employees ON Departments.dep_id = Employees.Dep_ID
```

cannot be parsed because it is not a complete query.  It is missing the opening clause, which in this case is a select clause.  Other options for an opening clause are insert, update, or delete.

It is also missing the keyword "from".  Also, while not mandatory, most select queries have a where clause to get just the records they want, as opposed to the entire database.

Comment: Because in the first query it's part of the from clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could be missing "SELECT FROM "?

Comment: Why is it not needed when it is part of the first query?